# SQL count deviation by 2

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this sql statement which list the id en name of all systems that have a specific report entry 'warning' and that don't appear in a table that list the explanation for that warning.

```
SELECT
  systems.id,
  systems.name
FROM
  systems
  LEFT JOIN reports ON (reports.system_id = systems.id)
  LEFT JOIN explanation_system_standards ON (reports.standard_id = explanation_system_standards.standard_id)
WHERE
  reports.status = 'warning' AND reports.datum = (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM reports) AND explanation_system_standards.dismissed_at IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT reports.standard_id
  FROM explanation_system_standards
  WHERE reports.standard_id = explanation_system_standards.standard_id AND reports.system_id = explanation_system_standards.system_id)
GROUP BY systems.id
```

This query returns accurate output. In this case 6 report entries with status 'warning' that do not appear in the explanation_system_standards table.

```
psql -d bidlqa_development -f fl.sql | grep testserver.com

 396 | testserver.com
 396 | testserver.com
 396 | testserver.com
 396 | testserver.com
 396 | testserver.com
 396 | testserver.com
```

However when I try to add the number of occurences via COUNT the result is +2 for every system.

```
SELECT
  systems.id,
  systems.name,
  COUNT (systems.id)
FROM
  systems
  LEFT JOIN reports ON (reports.system_id = systems.id)
  LEFT JOIN explanation_system_standards ON (reports.standard_id = explanation_system_standards.standard_id)
WHERE
  reports.status = 'warning' AND reports.datum = (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM reports) AND explanation_system_standards.dismissed_at IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT reports.standard_id
  FROM explanation_system_standards
  WHERE reports.standard_id = explanation_system_standards.standard_id AND reports.system_id = explanation_system_standards.system_id)
GROUP BY systems.id

psql -d bidlqa_development -f fl.sql | grep testserver.com
 396 | testserver.com            |     8
```

The reason it adds 2 is because of the explanation_system_standards.standard_id, there are 2 other systems in the table that use the same association. Does anybody know how i can correct this query to just give me the count on the per system base?

**EDIT:**

I fixed it, instead of a COUNT on system.id I needed a COUNT (DISTINCT reports.standard_id)

Comment: does this code work? there is a comma missing before your COUNT

Comment: correct, but that is not the issue, the copy and paste went wrong here :-)

Comment: Your examples are unclear and just add a lot of confusion to your question. On the first query you do a `GROUP BY systems.id`, (without aggregate function in the `SELECT` which is unlogical) and the results are showing 6 identical lines which is not possible with that `GROUP BY` query. Then on your second example the `systems.id` 396 shows a different  `systems.name` (from `testserver.com` to `lqas4409.mod.nl` ) Please rewrite all this and add **clarity**.

Comment: it does make sense since every report entry is just 1 line. a complete report per system consists of 176 rows per day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Distinct on your count;

```
SELECT
      systems.id,
      systems.name,
      COUNT (distinct systems.id)
    FROM
      systems
      LEFT JOIN reports ON (reports.system_id = systems.id)
      LEFT JOIN explanation_system_standards ON (reports.standard_id = explanation_system_standards.standard_id)
    WHERE
      reports.status = 'warning' AND reports.datum = (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM reports) AND explanation_system_standards.dismissed_at IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT reports.standard_id
      FROM explanation_system_standards
      WHERE reports.standard_id = explanation_system_standards.standard_id AND reports.system_id = explanation_system_standards.system_id)
    GROUP BY systems.id
```

Comment: unfortunately this reduces the disired output (6) to (1). I am trying to get the number of unregistered entries per system, so if the reports.standard.id which is coupled to report.status 'warning', does not appear in the explanation_system_standard table, this will count for 1. 6 unregistered entries will make 6.